# Google play iap customer details

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I recently launched mobile app I found a purchase made by the user for some reason for this transaction my app could not capture customer details nowhere I could find in console customer details like mail id phone number I was under impression iap report from Google play will provide all these details & hence in my app not annoying my users to provide their details at time of purchase but it looks like Google does not share these details

What is my next step?

Please help, don't want to keep my customer waiting

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does not provide the developer with customer details in the course of processing an IAP. This is probably "by design"; after all, if you don't need someone's personal information to complete the purchase, why should they give it to you?

Also note there are legal concerns here, such as [GDPR](https://eugdpr.org/). You may prefer that Google deals with all that heavy stuff, so you don't have to.

If you happen to have certain information at the time the order is made, you can supply it as the `developerPayload` member of the purchase. That will attach the information to your order. Otherwise, you're pretty much stuck with what you have.

Or, if you'd like to implement [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) in your app, you'll find that you can get a great deal of information about your user, at the cost of a single button press.

Comment: Thank you developerPayload is exactly what I wanted