# Android consumable in app purchase: get user information

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Is there a way to check which users bought when a consumable of my app? Not in the app itself but in the developer console/order management. Currently I only see an order id and a token, but would need some custom information or at least the user's email address or sth like that...

Comment: Wouldn't that be a privacy violation? I'm not sarcastic or anything, genuinely curious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google play iap customer details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948463/google-play-iap-customer-details)

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You'll need to link purchases to userIds yourself. Google will link that purchase to the users Play Store account, so they can potentially restore the purchase if they've reinstalled the app or gotten a new phone.

If you don't want to manage your own server, it may be worth using a tool like [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/), that offer a purchase/subscription backend-as-a-service.